# How to rewrite file codes with htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have wordpress install that is using html5. You most of us might know html5 uses new simplified code standard.

The problem that Im having is that although the base wordpress install is based on html5, the plugins are not...Actually, after doing a search in the entire site files, I find that even some of the wordpress files are not completely html5 using recent standards. When I run a w3 markup validation I get markup errors because of the mixed coding standards.

An example would be the newly refined javascript tag. If Im referencing a file then Im required to write the full tag, such as this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

But if the javascript is inline, then the "type" and "src" attribute are not require...

```
<script> CODE </script>
```

There are other code examples with this same problem throughout the entire install.

With their being a new version of wordpress every so often I need a way to rewrite these older standards within file codes to the newer html5 standards.

Im thinking the best option for something like this would using an htaccess file to do this. Most of the htaccess rewrite methods I found mostly deal with url and file name rewrites.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can do this? Id appreciate some help with this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for would be better done using Javascript.  Have you tried something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)? Including that at the very top of your code might sort things out.

Comment: Thanks Im going to test it out.